# sqlite3 and ruby query execution

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm having stupid problem executing a query. As I store integer in goals_num variable, I then intend to use it for another query but it won't run anything. However if instead of goals_num i insert 221 (which is what it contains anyway) the query is run i get result printed. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem?thanks!

```
 puts goals_num = db.execute("select MAX(goals) from EnglandTopScorers") 

 db.execute("select * from EnglandTopScorers where goals='#{goals_num}' ") do |row|
     puts row
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the return value of `db.execute`. If I recall this will return an array. Therefore `goals_num` is an array. To retrieve the value, you probably want to change it to:

```
 goals_num = db.execute("select MAX(goals) from EnglandTopScorers").first 
 db.execute("select * from EnglandTopScorers where goals='#{goals_num}' ") do |row|
     puts row
 end
```